# Global vs User Queue

Tags: swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I want to have a UI button press trigger a block of code, so I created a queue and dispatched a block to it async, but I'm not seeing the block start in a reasonable amount of time.

minimized example:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    ...
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "unique_label", qos: .userInteractive)

    @IBAction func on_press() {
        print("Touch")
        queue.async {
            // Stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So I see the "Touch" line in the console, but nothing from the async block happens.

Odd thing is, if I use `let queue = DispatchQueue.global()` instead, it seems to work as desired. So what is the operational difference between making my own queue, and using the global one here? I would have expected my QoS to give it some CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

> So what is the operational difference between making my own queue, and
>   using the global one here?

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "unique_label", qos: .userInteractive)
```

**creates the .serial queue** with high priority

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
```

doesn't actually create nothing but **returns global (system) .concurrent queue** with qos .default.

When you create Your own queue, the system will decide, on which global queue it will dispatch your execution request. The queue is not an execution engine ...

I am not able to believe, that your code is never executed, it is very unlikely to be true. If it happened, the trouble must be somewhere in your code which is not part of your question.